# WPF TextBox Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using two TextBox and "Save" Button. Basically, the "Save" button will be enabled when TextBox has any Text changed. I created a `CommandBinding` in the `Window.Resource` and "Save" `Button` uses `Command="Save"` and Two TextBox use `StaticResources` for Command binding.

However, the Button is not enabled when I change the text. Use Debug, I can see that my flag for the TextBox text changed is `True` but it looks like TextBox didn't trigger the `Save` Command `CanExecuted` Event.

Below is my code.

#### xaml

```
<Window>
<Window.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="NewCommand_Executed" />
            <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static commands:DataCommands.Requery}" Executed="RequeryCommand_Executed"/>
            <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static commands:DataCommands.ApplicationUndo}" 
                            Executed="ApplicationUndo_OnExecuted" CanExecute="ApplicationUndo_OnCanExecute"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Window.Resources>
        <CommandBinding x:Key="Binding" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"
                        Executed="SaveCommand_Executed" CanExecute="SaveCommand_CanExecute"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Command="New"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <Button Name="New"  Command="New" Content="New" Margin="3" Padding="3"/>
            <Button Name="Save" Command="Save" Content="Save"  Margin="3" Padding="3"/>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
        
        <TextBox Name="TbInputText1" TextChanged="TbInputText_OnTextChanged" Margin="5">
            <TextBox.CommandBindings>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="Binding"/>
            </TextBox.CommandBindings>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBox Name="TbInputText2" Margin="5" TextChanged="TbInputText_OnTextChanged">
            <TextBox.CommandBindings>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="Binding"/>
            </TextBox.CommandBindings>
        </TextBox>

        <ListBox Name="LsbHistory" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="3"></ListBox>

    </StackPanel>
```

#### behind-code

```cs
   public partial class UseCommand : Window
{
    private Dictionary<Object, bool> _isDirty = new Dictionary<Object, bool>();

    public UseCommand()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AddHandler(CommandManager.PreviewExecutedEvent,
            new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(CommandExecuted));
    }


    private void TbInputText_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // _isDirty.Add(sender, true);
        _isDirty[sender] = true;
    }

    #region Save 
    private void SaveCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDirty.ContainsKey(sender) && _isDirty[sender])
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }
    }


    private void SaveCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
        MessageBox.Show("About this controller: " + sender.ToString() +
                        "Contents: " + text);
        _isDirty[sender] = false;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Is there any step I missed? Why `CanExecuted` didn't be triggerd?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to move your save CommandBinding to <Window.CommandBindings> collection from the <Window.Resource> collection
2. remove the x:Key attribute
3. Set the Command property of your button to ""ApplicationCommands.Save"

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
   <CommandBinding
       CanExecute="SaveCommand_CanExecute"
       Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"
       Executed="SaveCommand_Executed"/>
(...)
</Window.CommandBindings>
<StackPanel>
(...)

<Button
   Name="Save"
   Margin="3"
   Padding="3"
   Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"
   Content="Save"
/>
(...)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the update. I can do that. However, There are Two TextBox are also using the `save` command. So the save button would have a different activity on different TextBox.

Comment: Oh... I think I found out. If you Use <Toolbar> instead of <Stackpanel> for these buttons. It actually works. When TextBox has text changed. It would enable the Save Button. Do you know what's the reason?

Comment: First of all i don't think TextBox control can invoke a command that's why `SaveCommand_CanExecute` and `SaveCommand_Executed` aren't called